invalid initialization of reference pair
I am doing coding questions on a site and I encountered a problem. I get this error from their compiler:
I get this too
sortmatrixlin.cpp:21:35:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2263:35: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::pair<int, int>&' from expression of type 'const std::pair<int, int>'
    while (__comp(*__first, __pivot))
                                   ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2266:34: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::pair<int, int>&' from expression of type 'const std::pair<int, int>'
    while (__comp(__pivot, *__last))

This is my code
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
std::map<int,int> map;
int n, m;
char c;
bool cmp(std::pair<int, int>& a, std::pair<int, int>& b) {
    if (c == '+') {
        return a.second < b.second;
    }
    else {
        return a.second > b.second;
    }
}
void Sort(std::map<int,int>& M){
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > v;
    std::map<int, int>::iterator it;
    for ( it = M.begin(); it != M.end(); it++)
    {
        v.push_back(*it);
    }
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), cmp);
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>::iterator itr=v.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            std::cout << itr->second << ' ';
            ++itr;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
int p = 0;
int main()
{
    std::cin >> n >> m>>c;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            int x;
            std::cin >> x;
            map.insert(std::pair<int, int>(p, x));
            p++;
        }
    }
    Sort(map);
}

My Visual Studio compiler doesn`t give any error.
This the question I tried to do:

Given a matrix with n rows and m columns and a character c which can
be + or -. To sort, by rows, the matrix ascending if the sign is + or
descending if the sign is -.
Sorting the array by lines is rearranging the elements so that,
traversing the array by lines, top to bottom and left to right, the
elements are in ascending/descending order.

I compiled it and ran it and it worked good but on their site it gives me an error

They seem to be using an ancient version of the C++ compiler. Avoid this site like the plague.

When I started learning C/C++ 10+ years ago, I had this exact compiler verison. D:

Unrelated: Did you know that you can pass a custom comparison function (like, say, your cmp to std::map? Or you could simply choose between regular (begin/end) and reverse iterators (rbegin/rend) when walking the map

where is const in cmp function?

Indeed: try cmp(const std::pair<int, int>& a, const std::pair<int, int>& b)

BTW all compilers seems to be happy with your code: https://godbolt.org/z/9earcMGKE with all warnings enabled and treated as errors. Please provide [mcve].

bool cmp(const std::pair<int, int>& a, const std::pair<int, int>& b) { or bool cmp(std::pair<int, int> a, std::pair<int, int> b) { Don't see any great need for references with a pair of int

Ok looks like you are using very very old compiler (gcc 4.8 from 2015) https://godbolt.org/z/snfshrhPM

@MarekR Technically it's not allowed and compiler can reject such code. See description of comp parameter in std::sort. And this is MCVE already, you are using wrong compiler version attempting to reproduce the problem. gcc 4.8 fails: https://godbolt.org/z/cK6ToGPdW

Why do I need to add 'const' in the custom comparator?

As user doctorlove said that made it work.
bool cmp(const std::pair<int, int>& a, const std::pair<int, int>& b) {
//       ^~~~~                         ^~~~~
    if (c == '+') {
        return a.second < b.second;
    }
    else {
        return a.second > b.second;
    }
}

I added const to the function. Thanks very much to all
